# Using the make command to compile class files

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

In my current computer science project, I've had to use a lot of classes and class files to help break up the enormous load of the program. However, I want to create a makefile that would be able to compile dependencies without using an intermediate ".o" step.
I already have:

```
%: %.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 $< -o $@
```

Yes, I do have to use c++11, not 14 or 17.
But is there a way to make it so that I can write `make foo.cpp bar.cpp` and have it run `g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp bar.cpp -o foo`?

Comment: `make foo.cpp bar.cpp` That doesn't make sense. You want to call make with the final target and provide a rule for it: `foo: bar.o foo.o`

Comment: Of course you can, just provide the rules for every binary you want to create, like @user0042 mentioned (I think this is what you wanted to ask for). Or even better, use CMake and you will have rules for all targets created automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want you'll have to list all of you `*.cpp` files as dependencies of `foo`, and do `make foo` (or have `foo` as the first target in your Makefile) to compile it.

```
foo: foo.cpp bar.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 $^ -o $@
```

`$^` stands for all the prerequisites.

However, why don't you want to use and intermediate step ? Doing it this way, every time any of your source files change, you will recompile and relink your whole project. Using `*.o` allows to avoid that :

```
foo: foo.o bar.o
    g++ -std=c++11 $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 $< -o $@
```

That way you'll avoid unnecessary recompilation.

(You can also omit the `%.o` rule, since make has built-in rules that are already defined by default)

Comment: True, but my problem is that I have a lot of classes that go into separate files. For example, I do have `foo` depending on `bar`, but I also have `foo1.cpp bar1.cpp` and `sn.cpp afu.cpp`. I'm looking for a way to simplify that so that I don't have to write the full console command for each instance. I've got around 80 classes that build into basically 50 different files, so writing all of that would suck. Plus, I still haven't finished, and the bug testing is arduous. I don't have an opposition to using `*.o` files, I just have so many of those that the rules would be awful to write out.

Comment: You don't have to list out every file you're compiling, you can just use wildcards if you want, to compile all .cpp files to .o files then compile all .o files to an executable.

Comment: What do you mean by "the full console command" ? Using that solution, you just would have to type `make foo` (assuming foo to be your main executable) to update your program. You indeed have to list your `*.cpp` files in your Makefile, but that is a one time cost. And, as pointed out by Sean Burton, you could use the make function $(wildcard) to avoid even that.